# Office 365 Private CDN does not working

Tags: office-365

I tried out Office 365 CDN capability feature as per the instruction mention in [Office 365 CDN announcement](https://dev.office.com/blogs/general-availability-of-office-365-cdn) video. I enabled both the public and private Cdn feature and also set libraries as a Cdn origins.

When I refer public Cdn URL for image/JavaScript it works great. When I refer image from private Cdn origin library, its URL doesn't reflect as private Cdn URL. I should get privatecdn.sharepointonline.com as prefix for image instead of asset library path URL.

I also verified list of Cdn origins and they listed out correctly without (configuration pending) indication

```
Get-SPOTenantCdnOrigins -CdnType Public/Private
```

Is there a way to make private Cdn works?

Comment: Make sure that your content has major version published in the Asset library.

Comment: Major version is already published

Answer (score 1):

that's because you cannot construct a URL for private CDN assets manually. 
When you make a request for these assets, their URLs are dynamically auto-rewritten.

For Public CDNs, the prefix is shared for all the items in the library / folder, so you can easily reuse the prefix cross all assets stored in same library / folder.
e.g.

*"https://publiccdn.sharepointonline.com//sites/site/library"*

Comment: Interesting. Can you help with this question related to public CDN URLs? https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/220435/office-365-public-cdn-what-does-the-public-actually-mean

Comment: Let's say I've uploaded an image in a private CDN default library SiteAssets. How can I access this image from a page? How do I construct the URL? Or in general how do I use a private CDN?