# Office 365 Public CDN - What does the Public actually mean?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, cdn

I'm trying out the Office 365 Public CDN feature as described [here](https://dev.office.com/blogs/office-365-public-cdn-developer-preview-release)

But I'm interested in what is "Public" about this. Towards the bottom of the article these is this answer in the Q&A:

> Can I use this CDN from outside of SharePoint Online?
>
> No. There is referrer limitation on the CDN URL requests. You can only
>   reference assets from the CDN URLs when request is coming from the
>   SharePoint Online.

This seems to suggest the files can't be accessed from outside of SharePoint Online.

So does this mean any authenticated user in my tenant has read access to the files in the CDN? Or any user in ANY tenant has read access (the "public" bit)?

Also, does anyone know if I enable CDN on a document library that's being used as an asset library that I'll need to update all my URLs? This seems to suggest I may not by now:

> Notice. During developer preview, you will need to explicitly update
>   the URL of shared assets in the pages and in the customizations to
>   match CDN URL addresses. We are however working on doing this
>   automatically with updated version, which is planned to be available
>   later this calendar year before full worldwide release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"public" means that technically files are available anonymously through the CDN URLs. There is referrer filtering, which will block Office 365 CDN to be used as the hosting location for assets which are not used in SharePoint.

It's important to notice that you will only expose static assets like JS files or images, not actual content. Only those which are located in the CDN origins.

If you use Public CDN option, there's no automatic URL rewrite.

If you, however, take advantage of the private CDN option, there are other differences as private CDN is only for authenticated users and URL rewriting happens automatically. Private CDN though means also that the CDN URL to assets is not static and keeps changing automatically.

Hopefully that clarified things a bit.

Comment: Hi Vesa, Are there any protections in place for referrer spoofing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, Vesa.  I'd add a comment onto your answer, but I don't have enough reputation.

Public - anonymously accessibly, but blocked for any traffic outside SPO (but still available for other tenant subscriptions outside of our own to access?)

Private - only available to authenticated users in my tenant? (+ all of the other rewrite rules, etc.)

Comment: I talked with Vesa via Twitter and he confirmed the above.  Also, I found good documentation in the "Choose whether each origin should be public or private" section here...
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-office-365-content-delivery-network-with-sharepoint-online-bebb285f-1d54-4f79-90a5-94985afc6af8